# How to ensure nvim uses my custom syntax files rather than the ones bundled with it?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I've been editing my syntax files, placing my versions in `~/.vim/syntax/`.

For `~/.vim/syntax/php.vim` that's worked, but for `~/.vim/syntax/html.vim` for some reason it's being overridden by `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/html.vim`.

Is there something I can put in my `.vimrc` file to make this choice explicit?  Or some other way?

(FWIW my `init.vim` declares `set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after`)

Comment: Is there any good reason to overwrite syntax fully rather than extend it? In any case, Vim always loads all sytax files matching "xyz.vim" found in runtimepath.

Comment: I guess simplicity - very easy to copy a file and add to/edit it.  I didn't know they could be extended and wouldn't obviously know how to.  Happy to learn though.

Comment: `:h after-directory`

Answer (score 1):

Vim (or NeoVim) will always load *all* syntax files it finds for a specific filetype.

To allow you to override the syntax configuration bundled in Vim runtime, those scripts typically include a check at the top that will skip the execution of the rest of the script if a variable is already set. For syntax files, that is typically the buffer-local variable `b:current_syntax` being set.

So you can override the shipped syntax by having your script run early in `'runtimepath'` (as you're already doing) and making sure that the `b:current_syntax` variable is set (to the name of the filetype used for syntax) at the end of the execution of your script.

See [`:help mysyntaxfile-replace`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile-replace):

> If you don't like a distributed syntax file, or you have downloaded a new
> version, follow the same steps as for [`mysyntaxfile`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile) above.  Just make sure
> that you write the syntax file in a directory that is early in `'runtimepath'`.
> Vim will only load the first syntax file found, assuming that it sets
> `b:current_syntax`.

For the `html.vim` type, there's one extra caveat, that it also checks for a `main_syntax` variable, which is used when `syntax/html.vim` is being sourced as part of another filetype that embeds HTML (such as PHP!)

See [this code snippet](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/html.vim#L12-L18):

```
" quit when a syntax file was already loaded
if !exists("main_syntax")
  if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
  endif
  let main_syntax = 'html'
endif
```

So, in order to override the bundled `syntax/html.vim`, you need to make sure that your script sets `b:current_syntax` (to `"html"`), and that it does *not* set (or `unlet`s) the `main_syntax` variable, to ensure the bundled script will finish execution early.